# Languages understandable to English-speakers without learning

Tags: international

There are groups of languages that are mutually intelligible.

For example, as a Russian, I can partially understand what is said to me in Ukrainian, Belorussian, Bulgarian, Czech, and some other languages, though I have never learned any of those languages.
I heard that Swedish people can understand Norwegian and Danish without specifically learning them.

The question is: How is it with the English language? Are there any languages that can be, at least partially (the overall meaning of the phrase spoken), understood by a person whose native language is English, provided that the person in question never learned any of these languages beforehand?

Comment: Probably a better fit for Linguistics.SE.

Comment: Some people claim (without support by scholars) that America and England speak different languages.

Comment: @GEdgar I have heard that they are two countries separated by the English language.

Comment: Here's [Eddie Izzard buying a cow in Frisian](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OeC1yAaWG34).

Comment: @Hugo - Frisian is supposedly the closest related language to English. For me, trying to understand it is a lot like trying to understand Middle English; the words look a lot like English, but I can't quite get there.

Comment: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/what-language-are-the-most-similar-to-english

Comment: This is technically known as "[mutually intelligibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_intelligible)," not "inter-understandibility."

Comment: Pig latin, though some would argue it's still "english".

Comment: livresque, that's a good point. I've usually heard of people saying that with the word "divided" instead of "separated". That would be the answer to the question from Highstaker.

Comment: @jwodder: My grammar teacher would have insisted on "mutual intelligibility", not "mutually".

Comment: @Hugo I can't even begin to ask you cake or death.  I'm covered in bees.

Comment: @Tristan Thank you.  I thought I had something off.  Idioms, eh?

Comment: @Hugo +1 for the link to Eddie Izzard. The best laugh I have had on EL&U for a while. BTW by  a similar logic, I find I can read Dutch, but I cannot even try to speak it;)

Comment: I think the fascinating thing is the English Australians and New Zealanders use. Yes, it is English but very different from American or British English. When an Aussie and Kiwi are talking with each other, Brits and Yanks can't tell the difference. But we Aussies and our Kiwi friends can.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Long story short: **no**.  Most native speakers of English who have no experience in any foreign language do not get much out of overhearing conversations in other languages.

David Ives, via the play ["Universal Language,"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAC&url=http://www.swarthmore.edu/SocSci/Linguistics/Papers/2007/gasser_emily.pdf&ei=OOEsUcCUDaqr0AHT0ICgBQ&usg=AFQjCNGqz9plCAylJFDyH0PElxufUx9uAA&bvm=bv.42965579,d.dmQ) (an artificial koiné for theatrical entertainment) might argue with me on this one, but with English being the bastard child of a language that it is, most native English speakers who have no experience with any foreign languages are **not** able to pick up more than a vague meaning when hearing unfamiliar languages, even those within the same "language family."

You would think, for example, that conversational German would be somewhat (can't say *easily*) accessible to a native English speaker, but aside from conversational pleasantries afforded us all by [UG](http://thebrain.mcgill.ca/flash/capsules/outil_rouge06.html), most anglophones do not understand German.  Despite the heavy French influence, most anglophones do not understand French, either, unless they study it or have some other intense exposure.

What you've described is an excellent question from a linguistics standpoint.  For example, I speak French, and I can understand the other Romance languages that I have not studied. It is interesting to note that native Spanish speakers often have trouble understanding conversational Portuguese, but native Portuguese speakers can work with conversational Spanish.

It does depend on your definition of "language" in relation to dialects.  There are many dialects that most native English speakers can understand, and there are also quite a few that are unintelligible depending on the region.  [Tangier Island](http://www.tangierisland-va.com/) is a great example of a remarkable preservation of the English of the Colonies.

Comment: +1 My wife claims that forty minutes into *Soldier of Orange* she stopped reading subtitles, and I once heard a program on Frisian and could understand maybe a third; on the other hand, most US speakers have great difficulty with braid Scots and other northern dialects: these are essentially closely related 'languages' for us.

Comment: @StoneyB A "must see" is *The Story of English*.  It could use a new installment for the last 30 years, but does have a segment where some Scotsmen being interviewed are subtitled.

Comment: "Tack för det."

Comment: As a Brazilian I can watch Spanish news despite never attending a class, and traveled through Argentina without speaking Spanish or English. I would rate it as 90%+ understandable. Never noticed an unilateral communication problem.

Comment: @Hugo Ding ding ding.

Comment: @livresque Funny. I live in (north) India and speak Hindi and Punjabi. I can understand parts of Pahari(Himachal Pradesh), Harayanvi, Bhojpuri(only about 50-60%) and a about quarter of the regional dialects in Rajasthan and Madhya Pradesh (don't know names of those). None of Kashmiri, though. The same goes for people in other parts of India, like somebody from one of the 4 southern states (Kerala, TN, Kr and AP) can understand the other 3 languages. I am not too sure about our North East. It is surprising how English does not provide such an implicit understanding of other related languages.

Comment: The closest I can come from my experience would be in combination with another language: If you are a native English speaker and learn German, congratulations, you are now literate in Dutch. (Good luck figuring out the pronunciation, though)

Comment: @livresque: "It is interesting to note that native Portuguese speakers often have trouble understanding conversational Spanish, but native Spanish speakers can work with conversational Portguese." A Portuguese guy once told me, it was the other way round.

Comment: @livresque As a native Portuguese I can attest by personal experience that most of the Portuguese understand pretty much everything of the [Galician language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galician_language) and have little to no trouble understanding [Castilian/Spanish language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language), but native Castilian speakers have trouble understanding Portuguese. A more technical explanation I've been presented is that Portuguese Phonemes include all the Castilian Phonemes, and the inverse is not true.

Comment: @NunoFreitas That’s because Galician and Portuguese were [the same language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galician-Portuguese) only a scant few centuries ago. Current arguments about whether they’re still dialects or are now separate languages tend to [devolve into political ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reintegrationism)

Comment: Im not sure what yiu mean in your reference to Tangier Islanders. Their accent is historically hardly noticeably different, only the slightest of colorings nowadays.

Comment: @Mitch As recently as two decades ago, the Tangier Islanders were such an insular community, literally, that they spoke an English so preserved from their ancestors, dating back to the settlement of the fishing community by speakers of BrE.

Comment: The Spanish/Portuguese question is complicated by the fact that Spanish is taught in schools in Portugal and in Brazil, but Portuguese is not generally taught in schools in Spanish-speaking countries.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the French and Latin influence on English is just too great for us to understand the other Germanic languages. Something like 35% of A1 (first 700 words by frequency) vocabulary is Romance, and the percentage only goes up over time, to about 60% of our core (non-specialized, non-academic) vocabulary. It's just too deep an integration, and it makes us sorta the odd man out in western European languages, straddling both the Germanic and Romance branches (though linguistically being part of the Germanic)

Comment: how about interlingua?!

Comment: @cregox What about it?  Do you think the question was about constructed languages like Esperanto or Interlingua (or even Unamunda, which is satire)?  What's more, few monolingual English speakers can get anything from it (should they encounter it) without a hard dose of Latin or any other related but mostly Western European language.  Would that they could.

Answer (score 17):

As near as I can tell, English is different than a lot of European languages in that scholars are much more inclusive. Where there are languages that other Germanic or Romance language speakers might call "separate languages", we would call "dialects". In other words, if two people can converse with each other in their own languages, and one is speaking English, then *by definition* they are both speaking English.

Not only that, but some dialects that *aren't* particularly mutually-intelligable are considered English. For instance, the first time I encountered full-blown [AAVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English), I couldn't understand a word. After years of heavy exposure I can mostly understand it now, but I can't speak it well. There's a joke about this in the movie [Airplane!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVJPB3W54Tc), where it is referred to as "[Jive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0j2dVuhr6s)". I recently had the same experience when two [Jamaicans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_English) started talking to each other (although they could have dropped into [Patois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_Patois). I'd have no way of knowing from one exposure)

I think the difference has to do with Nationalism. For example, Portugal and Spain have been separate countries for most of their existence. So as a matter of national pride, it simply wouldn't do for the Portuguese to refer to their tongue as "a dialect of Spanish", even if technically that's what it really should be. Similarly, Castilian speakers have been running Spain for a long time, and would not put up with people teaching their kids they speak some dialect called "Southern Castillian". They speak Spanish.

I submit that the same is probably going on with a lot of dialects of closely-related slavic "languages" that are associated with (actual or aspirational) national boundries. In fact, the accepted answer on [How are languages and dialects distinguished from each other?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/810/how-are-languages-and-dialects-distinguished-from-one-another) over on Linguistics.SE makes this exact claim.

Comment: They also speak Catalan in Spain, and a great deal of that region does not exactly cotton to their children being taught Castillian.  Interesting to consider the nationalism aspect.  I feel like the national boundaries do less to language barriers than the passage of time and the limits time can impose.

Comment: @livresque - For language drift itself, you are quite right. For what people want to call a separate "language", it appears to matter.

Comment: @T.E.D. I don't think any linguist believes Portuguese is "a dialect of Spanish". Galacian-Portuguese and Castilian (modern Spanish) have been [diverging for over a thousand years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Linguistic_map_Southwestern_Europe.gif), overtaking and absorbing their sister languages while diverging from each other. Mutual intelligibility aside, they have important pronunciation and vocabulary differences.

Comment: "A language is a dialect with an army and a navy" (attrib.  Max Weinreich).

Comment: @ghoppe - I took a jaunt over to Linguistics.SE, and had no trouble whatsover finding people of that opinion. For instance, you may want to look at http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/810/how-are-languages-and-dialects-distinguished-from-one-another , where the accepted answer used Serbian, Croatian, and Bosinan to make my exact point and http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/whats-the-difference-between-a-form-of-a-language-and-a-dialect-of-a-language , where the accepted answer defines languages in terms of mutual-unintelligability.

Answer (score 7):

The [Scots language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_Language) is most likely the closest to English, whether it's a distinct language or a just a dialect of English is controversial.
Here's a sample of Doric Scots: [How to speak Scots Doric](http://youtu.be/prQtLlRjJiE) [youtube].

Comment: Yes: it is called "Scotts" but is a rather obscure language spoken in Scotland. An English speaker can read and understand spoken Scotts although it will drive Grammar/Spelling Nazi's insane

Comment: https://sco.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_leid this one?

Comment: A large part of the scots Wikipedia pages were phony: https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2020/aug/26/shock-an-aw-us-teenager-wrote-huge-slice-of-scots-wikipedia

Comment: @jlliagre Oh yeah I saw about that on Reddit's r/linguistics. Absolute insanity

Answer (score 4):

Many scholars have studied the inter-dialect (language?) understanding of speakers of Swedish, Danish, and Norwegian. At recent meeting I attended, all Swedes, Danes, and Norwegians spoke their mother tongue and were understood. Einar Haugen, the great linguist, described the situation as Semicommunication: The Language Gap in Scandinavia. Non-specialist's understanding of neighbor-languages differs among the triad, and it turns out Norwegians are better at understanding Danish and Swedish than any other dyad. This may have something to do with attitudes (Norwegians grow up with hundred of dialects -- not to speak of two standard written languages -- bokmål and nynorsk.

I understand I am supposed to avoid asking for help, but I am trying to develop a method to measure the distance between languages (or dialects).

Answer (score 3):

No, not in the same sense as Spanish/Portuguese or Scandinavian languages.

You can often recognise some words in Danish/Dutch, especially if you have a northern English accent and it's fairly easy to follow the structure of a simple sentence in German (especially because most of the question words are similar)

You can make out some French vocabulary because of the same Latin origin.

Comment: So which is it, Danish or Dutch in Northern England?

Comment: @Mitch; I don't think it's English.

Answer (score 3):

Frisian and Norwegian are both fairly close to English. There are many cognates and similar grammar between them. The level of mutual intelligibility is not as high as amongst Romance or Slavic languages, though. Anecdotally, as a speaker of English and French, I understand about as much Spanish as I do Frisian—say 50–80% as well as the languages in which I’m fluent.

Still, it really depends on the situation and actual words used. Sometimes a cognate can sound unfamiliar; other times, a non-cognate can be inferred from context. And where spoken language fails, written language and gestures can help. There is more to communication than just speech.

As an aside, contact languages such as Scots have a very high level of mutual intelligibility with English. But that’s *because* of their contact with English, so I would discount them here.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Mutual Intelligibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_intelligibility) page on Wikipedia, Scots is the only language that is relatively mutually intelligible to English.  Personally, as an Anglophone, I can concur with that.

Additionally, I find Dutch to be the easiest distinct language to understand, both written and spoken.  While the grammar is different from English, there is a significant amount of vocabulary overlap and pronunciation similarity.  The mutual intelligibility is partial and perhaps asymmetric, but one can often discern the meanings of the majority of the words in a sentence, and correctly infer the grammar.  [Quoting Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_language):

> Dutch has a relatively close genetic relationship to the descendants of Old and Middle English (such as English and Scots), though less than the Frisian languages (such as West Frisian) have to English. Both Dutch and English belong to the West Germanic languages and both lack most or all of the High German consonant shift that characterizes the descendants of Middle High German (such as German and Yiddish). Because of their close common relationship many English words are essentially identical to their Dutch lexical counterparts, either in spelling (begin) or pronunciation (boek = book, diep = deep), or both (lip); these cognates or in other ways related words are excluded from this list.

The intelligibility is very apparent for short, grammatically simple sentences.  For example:

> Spreek u Engels?                                                                         (Do you speak English?)

If so,

> Dit is goed nieuws!                                                                      (That is good news!)

Because, if

> u bent goed in wat u doet,                                                          (you are good in what you do)

then I'll bet you can understand some Nederlands!

Answer (score -8):

> The question is: how is it with English language?

While not exactly another language, American English comes close to this. It can be understood generally by speakers of the English kind of English but, has a lot of differences in words, names, pronunciations and cultural references that in order to be understood, requires the listener to spend time learning about them.

Comment: Don’t be ridiculous. Not merely “not exactly separate languages”, they are not in any way, shape, or fashion separate languages. American English is English, just as Mexican Spanish is Spanish.  These are not separate languages, despite your constant campaigning to make people agree with you about this. If you think otherwise, please compare English with French, German, or Chinese — *that* is what it means to be separate languages.  Don’t mislead yourself into thinking that differences of  dialect, accent, register, or even technical vocabulary count as separate languages: they don’t.

Comment: I didn't state that it is a separate language. I stated that American English comes close to being so.

Comment: And you were wholly wrong in your statement.  It comes nothing whatsoever “close” to being so. Please study other languages so you learn what language is; you cannot do so from studying your own.

Comment: It is not wise to **assume** anything, about me or anyone else. As I wrote in my answer, American English has a lot of differences. They are not just something that I have stated but, they can easily be seen by searching the internet for lists of them.

Comment: So what? Lots of dialect pairs have lots of so-called differences. Doesn’t make them different languages. You simply speak a different dialect.

Comment: A wise colleague of mine has said many times (in re: teaching SL/L2/L1) that *there is no great talent in speaking your native language.*